# Update the CSS of a Website without refreshing the Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I've created a page with CSS. Now I must change from my editor to my browser and refresh the full page, just to have a look at every little change. But I don't want to refresh the page, because I have some animations.

So is there anything which I can use that my site updates automatically after a CSS update?
Maybe with JavaScript, jQuery, Ajax or something?

Comment: You can use the developerstoolkit of chrome to test changes on the fly to your website, and if it's working, you can add it to your .css file...

Comment: Hi @all. Now i search the same but for changes in the HTML files! Anyone?

Comment: @Karen, Please post a new question as this would require an entirely different answer.

Comment: +1 for @TWCrap 's recommendation. I do that all the time.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Here you are: http://cssrefresh.frebsite.nl/

CSSrefresh is a small, unobstructive javascript file that monitors the CSS-files included in your webpage. As soon as you save a CSS-file, the changes are directly implemented, without having to refresh your browser.

Just insert the javascript file and it works!

But note: It only works when you have the files on a server!

---

### Edit: LiveStyle

If you develop with [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/) and Google Chrome or Apple Safari, then you should use [Emmet LiveStyle](http://livestyle.emmet.io/). This is a more powerful Live CSS-Reloader.
Now I use it instead of *CSS Refresh*.

If you want more information about this awesome plugin, please read the [Post by Smashing Magazine](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/08/08/release-livestyle-css-live-reload/)

Comment: this is nice, but you mustn't forget to remove it before deploying your website to the production environment, otherwise you impose quite a bit of unnecessary load on the server.

Comment: @dTDesign, If this is the correct answer, why is there a bounty?

Comment: I'm not so long on this forum. Firstitried what this is, and i earnd a badge. And i don't mark it cause itneeds some answer, its marked cause its need more attention. My answer isnt the only one which is correct.

Comment: @dTDesign should work with eclipse? because I have already tested and seems is not working or I must put the js on server and not locally?

Comment: @mcmwhfy: insert the js AFTER the css and it only works on a server. it works also with xampp or something...

Comment: all it does is checking if the server reports a different modify time for the file by doing ajax head reqiests to the server. when the time differs it will reload the file by replacing the src of the css file by the same path including a random number at the end. personaly i would prefer timestamps instead of random numbers but i think its still a good solution for this.

Answer (score 10):

With jQuery you can create a function that reloads external stylesheets.

```
/**
 * Forces a reload of all stylesheets by appending a unique query string
 * to each stylesheet URL.
 */
function reloadStylesheets() {
    var queryString = '?reload=' + new Date().getTime();
    $('link[rel="stylesheet"]').each(function () {
        this.href = this.href.replace(/\?.*|$/, queryString);
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer

first i try the proposal by dTDesign, cause i look a lil bit easier, cause I'm not familiar with jquery...
but thanks again

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at http://livereload.com/.

It works as a browser plugin for OS X and windows. I like it because I do not have to embed additional javascript which I could accidentally commit in my versioning control.

Answer (score 4):

I find browser plugins/extensions to be the easiest solution. They don't require any code changes to your individual sites. And they can be used for any site on the web — which is useful if I modify something in-memory real quick to hide a toolbar or fix a bug temporarily; once finished mucking with it, I can press a key and all the CSS is back to normal.

Once installed, (most) CSS reloaded plugins/extensions don't reload the CSS automatically. But usually work with something as simple as a toolbar button, a context menu item, and/or a simple key press to reload the CSS. I find this method is less error prone anyway, and is much less complicated then some of the automated solutions out there.

Some examples (feel free to suggest some others):

Chrome:

- [tin.cr](http://tin.cr/) (includes automatic reload, and can persist in-browser changes to source files)
- [CSS Refresh](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/css-refresh/ojcnooebgeenefpfngjfifjcnhlkbbdd)

Firefox:

- [CSS Reloaded](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/css-reloader/)
- [CSS Refresh](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/css-refresh-199425/)

Answer (score 3):

Here is my little Project. Please give it a try
[CSS Auto reload on Github](http://nv.github.com/css_auto-reload/)

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can manipulate the `CSS` via `jQuery`:

```
$(".classToBeReplaced").switchClass( "classToBeReplaced", "newClass", 1000 );
```

You could also use the `toggleClass` method.

http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

http://jqueryui.com/demos/switchClass/

Comment: tanks.

but its the same like Sebass van Boxel.
I'm not familiar with jquery... 
but thanks again :)

Answer (score 2):

Firebug for FireFox.

It's a plugin in an attached/separate window. Changes to HTML/CSS appear instantly, elements are highlighted.

Advantage over JS hacks is that you can't copy this accidentally to your production instance.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for Live Reload:

It's available as a browser extension and easy to implement

http://livereload.com/

Answer (score 1):

The new open-source code editor, [brackets](http://brackets.io/), has a **Live Development** feature where you can edit CSS in the editor and it will immediately be reflected in the chrome browser. It currently only works for CSS editing, but HTML editing is coming soon!

Answer (score 1):

Firebug for Firefox is my prefered method:
https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/firebug/
You can edit HTML and CSS on the fly, quickly deactivate CSS rules (without deleting them), add or remove HTML and so on. If you wan't to tweak your design this is your choice. You can even save changes to a local copy, but I hardly ever use that feature.

Answer (score 0):

This might help -> [chaicode](http://chaicode-3lads.rhcloud.com/)

Its a live CSS, Javascript and HTML editor that is opensource and a wip.
[github](http://github.com/zeusdeux/chaicode)

Comment: Provided link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Firefox then you can install Web Developer Toolbar 1.2.2 from Add-on of Firefox which has option of Reload Linked Stylesheets.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [CSS Brush](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/css-brush/mamnhhinmmdpcipjnhflillmhnogoobj?hl=en-US), a chrome plugin for creating CSS live. You needn't have to write all CSS in a text editor, come back to browser and reload it, rather write the CSS live as if you were doing it in a text editor. You will have more features than a text editor here like context-sensitive-menu, use duplicate properties, select complete CSS path or a filtered path of a element directly from the page.